# Permissions on /vagrant directory

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-12.04, vagrant

I have a vagrant instance setup e.g

```
~/Vagrants/devmachine
```

which has my webapp source code setup like

```
~/Vagrants/devmachine/htdocs/myapp
```

which is mapped to /var/www on instance/guest machine (symilink)

```
ls -al /var/www
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Apr  4 10:16 /var/www -> /vagrant/htdocs/myapp/
```

The issue is that I am unable to change own of the /var/www files e.g

```
ls -al /var/www/
total 80
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   782 Mar 20 06:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   102 Apr  4 07:06 ..
```

What I am try to is change:

```
 sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www
```

Command is executed without error but file user/group for /var/www does not change

The reason to keep files in this way is so I can edit files easily by IDE.

**Edit**

I added this to Vagrantfile, but still apache2 is unable to write to files

```
config.vm.share_folder("v-root", "/vagrant", ".", :owner => "vagrant", :group => "www-data")
```

Comment: this might be the issue http://jeremykendall.net/2013/08/09/vagrant-synced-folders-permissions/

Answer (score 1):

To do this sort of thing I add a second shared folder like so in my VagrantFile:
`config.vm.synced_folder "../project_folder", "/var/www/", owner: "apache", group: "apache"`

so that I can explicitly set the permissions of that folder without effecting the default vagrant setup.